# Ordenamiento de nombres

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Buenas noches tengo el siguiente problema

En excel tengo un listado de nombres parecido asi

Nombres y apellidos  | edad | sexo

Juan Miguel Aguirre  | 24 |M

Maria Ines Lozada.   | 25 |F

Juan Carlos Chimbo.  | 32 |M

Aida Mercedes Armendariz |45 |F

Luis Alfredo Medina |31|M

Queria saber como se podria ordenar de manera alfabetica por apellido, en este caso el tercer texto viene siendo el apellido

Comment: Hola. Si todos los nombres y apellidos son tres siempre  ¿No te es más práctico separarlos en columnas y ordenas recién ahí? ¿O acaso estás obligados a tenerlos en una sola columna?

Comment: El problema es que los nombres ya estan en una sola columna

Comment: Por eso pregunté ¿Estás obligado a que sigan en una sola columna? ¿Son siempre tres nombres y apellidos?

Comment: Tu mejor opción es poner el apellido en otra columna y ordenar por esa columna. Si no, tendrás que programar algo en VBA bastante complejo para hacerlo y no compensa.

Comment: Exacto osea en pocas la tabla me entregaron con la información y estoy obligado a que siga en una sola columna el nombre y apellido completos, pensaba en dividir en columnas los campos que componen el nombre completo luego ordenar y finalmente hacer una concatenación para q vuelvan a estar en una sola columna

Comment: Pues ya lo tienes. Esa es la solución. Sacas el apellido en una columna, ordenas por esa columna y eliminas esa columna. No necesitas siquiera concatenar, tan solo extraer el apellido en otra columna. El problema es sacar el apellido, porque en tu ejemplo siempre es la tercera palabra, pero supongo que en la realidad no siempre será así. PAra eso no hay solución.